# Using LaTeX and TikZ with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, patterns, latex, mathematics

When using Adobe Illustrator I wish I could just program things sometimes, like I do with Ti*k*Z & LaTeX. Are there any plugins or extensions or general workflows that can help unite these two concepts, beyond simply importing a PDF?

Here's an example of an ornamental pattern I programmed with LaTeX & Ti*k*Z. It's basically a 50 sided polygon with each vertex connected to every other vertex by an edge:

[image]

Comment: You can place an external file. If you now eecompile the thing illustrator updates. I do this all the time with EPS files (as they compile faster than a latex document, illustrator is after all a EPS compiler reference implementation)

Comment: By the way i have actually demonstrated this particular example before

Comment: @joojaa demonstrated where?